# addressing a big.matrix from cluster workers

Tags: r, r-bigmemory, rparallel

I am trying to access a big.matrix (not file backed) from a parLapply function on a windows machine. However, R crashes when calling the big.matrix - "R for Windows front-end stopped working".

Do I need to attach the big.matrix first? How do I do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
require(parallel)
require(bigmemory)

data <- matrix(rnorm(10^8),ncol=1000)
data.big <- as.big.matrix(data)

cl <- makeCluster(2)

parLapply(cl,1:2,function(x,data.big){
  require(bigmemory)
  data.big[x,1] # this line causes R to crash
},data.big)

stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `attach.big.matrix` to access the shared memory.  This is done by using the information from `describe`.  The following should work.

```
datadesc <- describe(data.big)

parLapply(cl,1:2,function(x,datadesc){
  require(bigmemory)
  data.big <- attach.big.matrix(datadesc)
  data.big[x,1] # this line causes R to crash
},datadesc)
```